# Given a 2D Numpy array representing a 2D distribution, how to sample data from this distribution with the aid of Numpy or Scipy functions?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Given a 2D numpy array `dist` with shape `(200,200)`, where each entry of the array represents the joint probability of (x1, x2) for all x1 , x2 ∈ {0, 1, . . . , 199}. How do I sample bivariate data **x** = (x1, x2) from this probability distribution with the aid of Numpy or Scipy API?

Comment: please give input & output example

Comment: You can check the input array by downloading [this .npy file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xkUwjnl2rBNfPOk2Tw6eVDhES2Fj45Ll/view)

The output should be an Numpy array with shape `[Sampling Size, 2]`. e.g. If Sampling size ==2, the output might be [[122,199],[182,28]]
Actually, It's from the course assignment of cs294-158 (I am not taking this course, just out of personal interest), you can check [2 Two-dimensional data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DtYllaV4Yk8ljgYcLBmdXNplEDTG6HT6/view)

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This solution works with probability distributions of any number of dimensions, assuming they are a valid probability distribution (its contents must sum to 1, etc.). It flattens the distribution, samples from that, and adjusts the random index to match the original array shape.

```py
# Create a flat copy of the array
flat = array.flatten()

# Then, sample an index from the 1D array with the
# probability distribution from the original array
sample_index = np.random.choice(a=flat.size, p=flat)

# Take this index and adjust it so it matches the original array
adjusted_index = np.unravel_index(sample_index, array.shape)
print(adjusted_index)
```

---

Also, to get multiple samples, add a `size` keyword argument to the `np.random.choice` call, and modify `adjusted_index` before printing it:

```
adjusted_index = np.array(list(zip(*adjusted_index)))
```

This is necessary because `np.random.choice` with a `size` argument outputs a list of indices for each coordinate dimension, so this zips them into a list of coordinate tuples. This is also *much* more efficient than simply repeating the first code.

---

Relevant documentation:

- [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)
- [`np.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way, but I'm sure there's a much more elegant solution using scipy.
`numpy.random` doesn't deal with 2d pmfs, so you have to do some reshaping gymnastics to go this way.

```
import numpy as np

# construct a toy joint pmf
dist=np.random.random(size=(200,200)) # here's your joint pmf 
dist/=dist.sum() # it has to be normalized 

# generate the set of all x,y pairs represented by the pmf
pairs=np.indices(dimensions=(200,200)).T # here are all of the x,y pairs 

# make n random selections from the flattened pmf without replacement
# whether you want replacement depends on your application
n=50 
inds=np.random.choice(np.arange(200**2),p=dist.reshape(-1),size=n,replace=False)

# inds is the set of n randomly chosen indicies into the flattened dist array...
# therefore the random x,y selections
# come from selecting the associated elements
# from the flattened pairs array
selections = pairs.reshape(-1,2)[inds]
```

Comment: How would the `reshape(-1,2)` look if we had a 3d table ( one more dimension). thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment either, but @applemonkey496 's suggestion for getting multiple samples doesn't work as written. It's an excellent solution otherwise.

Instead of

```
adjusted_index = np.array(zip(*adjusted_index))
```

adjusted_index should be converted to a python list before trying to put it into a numpy array (numpy arrays do not accept zipped objects), eg:

```
adjusted_index = np.array(list(zip(*adjusted_index)))
```

Comment: good catch! i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but to improve kevinkayaks answer's :

```
pairs=np.indices(dimensions=(200,200)).T
selections = pairs.reshape(-1,2)[inds]
```

Is not needed can be replace by :

```
np.array([inds//m, inds%m]).T
```

The matrix "pairs" is not needed anymore.